# Display data from database from ID

Tags: php

I have a database set up and I use 'user_id' for example to displays the name, age, address etc. I want to display all information with just the id in php. This then echos in another page. Currently i have to do this:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Name'] = $row['Name'];
        $_SESSION['Address'] = $row['Address'];
```

Comment: you badly need to edit your question.

Comment: I need to have user_id to represent all user details information without the need to echo each row individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store just the user ID and a token that you set when the user logged in:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $user = // Query your database to get the user with that ID.
} else {
    // Not logged in.
}
```

Alternatively, you could use secure sessions and serialize the user's profile object into a string, but you will need to keep it updated in case the user changes their information.